# Form action="/cron.php"

Tags: 7, forms, blocks, caching, cron

I got a custom form in a block, wich is available on my homepage.
After e while the form action changes to action="/cron.php" instead of action="/nl". 
I can't figure out where this fault is comming from.

My Drupal Website got standard block caching enabled. If i clear the cache, the form is back to normal. After a while it goes back to "/cron.php" and i have to clear the cache again.

```
  <form action="/nl" method="post" id="dms-locator-filter-form" accept-charset="UTF-8">
  to
  <form action="/cron.php" method="post" id="dms-locator-filter-form" accept-charset="UTF-8">
```

Annyone an idea where this fault/strange behaviour could come from?

Comment: how are you creating the form?

Comment: custom form :) , with form api of drupal

Comment: can you post the code?